# Why can't my kitten meow?

Tags: cats

I have a 12 week old kitten and everytime he tries to meow it sounds like he lost his voice and can't get anything out. Should I be concerned?

Comment: Can you share more information? Like it was from beginning or recent development? Any recent disease? Any injury?

Comment: Did the kitten used to meow?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming he has always meowed like this:

Every cat has a different meow, some meow long and deep while others are short and squeaky.

Their voice can change as they age however some keep their kitten mews.

Comment: I think this is not a perfect answer. You cannot assume anything. Unless the OP gives all necessary details needed to answer the question, the question remains unanswerable and should have close vote

Comment: You are correct, which is why im giving an assumption answer that this is a healthy kitten until he clarifies the question. If he never comes back then yes i will vote to close it but it has only been 12 hours.

Comment: Not adding the assumption would make people think that it is always normal which is not the case.